# Custom function to find a role (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a custom function to find a specific role in my discord server. The end goal is to use it in some code for a command, Take this for example:

```py
Staff = 806757393378836480
```

```py
@commands.command
async def test(self, ctx, role):
     find_role(Staff) # function i want to use
     await ctx.send(Staff.mention + " I pinged the staff!")
```

I have a whole list of all the roles in my discord stored in a .py file. Ex:

```py
# Reaction Roles
UploadNotifications = 806806814792089660
LivestreamNotifications = 806807089962811422
DeadChatNotification = 823387834501038101
BumpNotification = 813259572742848512

# Member
Member = 806762200478777404
Everyone = 726514695523008514
```

At the end of the file, I want to make a function that will get the desired role.

```py
def find_role(role):
    return discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.id == """desired role id""", guild.roles)
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to go about this. Any ideas are helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. I would add the code step by step and explain what all you have to do so as to get the desired result.

#### Aim: Create a function that finds and returns the role requested by the user.

## Steps:

#### 1. Create a dictionary which contains the name of the roles has KEY and their VALUE are role's id.

```
roles = {"UploadNotifications": 806806814792089660, "LivestreamNotifications": 806807089962811422, "DeadChatNotification": 823387834501038101, "BumpNotification": 813259572742848512, "Member": 806762200478777404, "Everyone": 726514695523008514}
```

This dictionary contains every role you have mentioned above. So now we will be using this dictionary to extract the desired role. Write this code at the top after declaring the Bot variable.

#### 2. Creating `role_id()` function to take out the value of the key (name of the role).

Here I will be creating a `for` loop that will return us the id of the role we asked for.

```
def role_id(role): # You would need to enter the name of the role in this 'role' attribute
    for key, value in roles.items():
        if key == role:
            return value
```

This code would return the value which is the role id. This you would be able to use it anywhere you want to.

---

I hope I was able to explain this to you. If still there is an error, feel free to ask me and I would gladly help you. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: You can simply do `return roles.get(role, None)` instead of that for-loop.

Comment: But here I have a dictionary with a Key Value pair.

Comment: That doesn't really answer anything, you could've simply do: `return roles[role]`, I was using the `dict.get` method to set a default value of `None` in case there's a `KeyError`

Comment: Oh! That's fine! Add your answer. It would be of help. :D

Comment: This would probably work best for me. Thanks!